# IndexError...out of range,

Tags: python, indexing, range

Following on from the awesome help from earlier, I now have an issue with exception handling.
I've got a list of 11 plots to be selected by their index number. If the user selects higher than 11, it should request they re-enter but atm, I get IndexError: list index out of range.
I would've thought the except line would just handle anything else...but it must just be a missing line??

```
try:
    response = raw_input("Select a monitoring plot from the list (0-11): ")
    if response == 'q':
        confirm = raw_input('Confirm quit (y/ n)...')
            if confirm == 'y':
                print 'Bye'
                break
            else:
                continue
    selected = dataList[int(plotSelect) + 1]
    print 'You selected : ', selected[1]
except ValueError:
    print "Error: Please enter a number between 0 and 11"
```

Comment: What's that `plotSelect`? Is it supposed to be `response`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`except ValueError` only catches a `ValueError`. You need to add `IndexError` as well:

```
except (ValueError, IndexError):
```

Answer (score 0):

`except ValueError` means you only catch execptions of the type `ValueError`. Include a catch for `IndexError` if you want to handle it differently, or catch both and handle it the same way.

Answer (score 0):

`ValueError` will come up when he user inputs something that isn't a number. (So `int("hello")` throws `ValueError`)

`IndexError` is thrown when the user inputs a number greater than the number of elements in the list. (Eg, `range(5)[7]`

You may want to try getting your first input with a loop like the following

```
resp = ""
while resp not in ('0', '1', ... '10', 'q'):
    resp = raw_input(...)
```